# How can I change color of ComboBox's selected item in drop down menu in WPF?

Tags: xml, wpf

So basically I just want to change the light blue color of a selected item of a drop down menu that appears when ComboBox's arrow is pressed.

[image]

```
<ComboBox Foreground="White" Name="comboBoxStatus" SelectedValue="{Binding 
SelectedContact.Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3E4147" />
                   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#292B2F" />
          </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

And also is there a way to change the ComboBox's arrow color on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override the default Style for the `ComboBoxItem`. This is because the highlight appearance is implemented in the `ControlTemplate` (using fixed/static color resources)

The following example shows a shortened but working Style containing only the relevant visual state triggers to satisfy your requirement.
The complete Style can be found at [Microsoft Docs: `ComboBox` Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Its recommended, to extract the template using the XAML designer or Blend. Either way will work.
Following the above link will give you additional visual states that you could be interested in to implement customized triggers for ([`ComboBoxItem` States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#comboboxitem-states)). Otherwise copy & paste the missing states.

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedItemHighlightColor">#3E4147</Color>
  </Style.Resources>

  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="2"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemHighlightColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you just tell me where should I put this template ovveride? In the resource dictionary or...?

Comment: Depends on the scope you want the Style to be applied. You can add it to any parent ResourceDictionary (parent of the ComboBox) or to the ResourceDictionary of the ComboBox itself. For example `ComboBox.Resources` or `Window.Resources` or `Application.Resources` (in App.xaml). If you want it to aplly to *every* ComboBox 8globally) then App.xaml is the right place.

Comment: one more question... now the problem is that the background of a popup part is white... how can I make it light gray?

Comment: The Popup is part of the ComboBox template. You would have to edit it. If you follow the link provided in my example, you will find an example template of the ComboBox (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#combobox-controltemplate-example). Locate the Style that targets the ComboBox. Within the ControlTemplate locate the Popup element. The Popup usually contains a root element that is a Border. Set the Background of this Border to your desired color.